# Assigning consecutive integers to a list of variables

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

How to rewrite the following in a more compact form?

```
constexpr unsigned int dog=1;
constexpr unsigned int cat=2;
constexpr unsigned int elephant=3;
...
constexpr unsigned int zebra=1000;
```

Ideally, I'd like something like

```
dog,cat, elephant, ..., zebra = range(1,1000)
```

Comment: Just write a function?

Comment: It's probably better to explain what problem you're trying to solve with these variables, not how you're currently trying to solve it. You can't 'generate' variables with different names. But there might be other ways to say 'given 3 alphabetical letters, calculate a number' that _do_ work.

Comment: The variable names are not necessarily consecutive. I make that clearer in the snippet.

Comment: Use a ````std::array```` or a ````std::map````. Or 42. That is the exact answer to your question.

Comment: I don't think I can do that for constexpr variables.

Comment: As @ArminMontigny suggested, you can use a map. Do you mean more compact in terms of syntax, in which case you can write: `constexpr unsigned int dog=1, cat=2, ...`. You'll get more helpful suggestions if you explain your actual problem rather than the attempted solution.

Comment: Or you can save a few characters by just using `enum`. I can't tell if that solves your problem though, because you won't tell us what it is.

Comment: I'm refactoring code and noticed a block of constexpr assignments which I'm trying to simplify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Assigning consecutive integers to a list of variables

They're not really variables if they can't vary.

You can just replace

```
constexpr unsigned int dog=1;
constexpr unsigned int cat=2;
constexpr unsigned int elephant=3;
...
constexpr unsigned int zebra=1000;
```

with

```
enum Animal: unsigned {
  dog=1,
  cat,
  elephant,
  ...
  zebra
};
```

if that's all you want.

Comment: Just wanted to comment why this is exactly what I'm looking for. The enum declaration allows me to control the integer start value and also control the type of integer. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what are you trying to do? If you are trying to enumerate a list, you should use **enum** instead. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

Comment: please do not use answers to ask for clarification of the question

Comment: I have asked for reassurance and answered, my dear friend.